# NEST aggs collection is read only

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the NEST client with the following syntax:

```
 _server.Search<Document>(s => s.Index(_config.SearchIndex)
.Query(q => q.MatchAll(p => p)).Aggregations(
    a => a
    .Terms("type", st => st
        .Field(p => p.Type)
    )));
```

However I keep getting the following exception

```
  A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

  Additional information: Collection is read-only.
```

It only seems to occur when I'm using aggregations, the field of Type has the following mapping:

```
  [Keyword(Name = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you are accessing the result and are you trying to change the result object?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: i have the same problem.. can figure this out. the problem is in the deserialization of the response. the exceptions origins in JSON.NET.
@Imran Azad, how did you solve this eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check the versions of NEST and Elasticsearch.Net that you are using. I just tried the following example with Elasticsearch 5.1.2 and NEST 5.0.1 and don't see the issue

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Document>(mm => mm.AutoMap())
        )   
    );

    var documents = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i =>
        new Document
        {
            Type = $"Type {i % 5}"
        }
    );

    client.IndexMany(documents);

    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
        .Index(defaultIndex)
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll(p => p))
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("type", st => st
                .Field(p => p.Type)
            )
        )
    );

    foreach (var bucket in searchResponse.Aggs.Terms("type").Buckets)
        Console.WriteLine($"key: {bucket.Key}, count {bucket.DocCount}");
}

public class Document
{
    [Keyword(Name = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

this outputs

```
key: Type 0, count 20
key: Type 1, count 20
key: Type 2, count 20
key: Type 3, count 20
key: Type 4, count 20
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know what I did but it seems to be working now!